# How to arrange text to start from the bottom of div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have text inside the element to be aligned such that it begins from the bottom of the page. I want it so that as I increase or decrease the width of the div, the text fills up the bottom first before the top.

I want to look like the following design from adobe illustrator:

[image]

Instead, it looks like the following:

[image]

the code used in the second image is below:

```
<style media="screen">
  *{
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  }
  .big-intro-text{
    font-size: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;

  }
  .big-intro-text div{
    border: solid 1px green;
    text-align: left;
    color: gray;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
  }
</style>

<div class="big-intro-text" align = "center">
  <div>home of the zebras</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we change the HTML? @progr

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
}

.big-intro-text {
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

.big-intro-text div {
  border: solid 1px green;
  text-align: left;
  color: gray;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-intro-text" align="center">
  <div><span>home<span> of the zebras</div>
</div>
```

Try this code.

Comment: Try this @progr

Answer (score -1):

You could add a large amount of margin on the top, and reduce the div height.

Sorry about the old answer, I did not understand the question.